# How can I sort that dictionary with the attribute of a Django object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, dictionary

I have two dictionaries like that :

```
a = {'id_1': ob1, 'id_2': ob2}
b = {'id_1': 'test1', 'id_2', 'test2'}
```

and ob1, ob2 are Django object with two properties : `name` and `country`

And I would like to sort the dict b according the property name.

I thought to sorted obviously but it does not work ...

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: What would be the output here? A list with `test1` and `test2` sorted according to the `.name`s of `obj1` and `obj2`?

Comment: Also dictionaries aren't really meant to be ordered, why don't you use a list instead? (your usecase doesn't particularly imply need of a dictionary, `id_1` and `id_2` don't really make much sense)

Comment: IF you want to *order* a *dict* you should use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of regular `dict`. Dicts aren't orderable by definition.